# I need help ( Logic )

Tags: java

My code has no syntax errors, but when I start the program I do not get the message in the console as I supposed to get

```
class verschlüsselung {

    private static void search(int b, int a) {

        b = 1;
        Random r = new Random();
        a = r.nextInt(9);
        System.out.println(a);

        while (a != b) {
            for (b = 0; b == 9; b++) {
                if (b == a) {
                    System.out.println("found the number " + b);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        search(0, 0);
    }
}
```

I am thankful for every explanation.

Comment: Using umlauts in class names is discouraged.

Comment: "I do not get the message in the console as I supposed to get" What is your code suppose to do? What output do you expect?

Comment: Your loop executes only when `a!=b` and inside you check for `if(b == a)` which is always false

Comment: i was expecting :
1. "a"
2. "found the number + b " 
but i only got "a"

Comment: Why do you call search with two parameters, you use neither of both

Comment: @karthikr but at the biggining a!=b and therefor i want to search for a

Answer (score 0):

The condition in your loop should be `b < 9`, otherwise you never enter in its body. However, the best way to do what you want is :

```
b = 0;
while (a != b) b++;
System.out.println("found the number " + b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. like the other guys mentioned: you should switch `b == 9` with `b < 9` (so that the for-loop body  will execute while b is smaller than 9)
2. after the "found the number " printing you should add a `return;` statement - otherwise you might get yourself into an infinite (while) loop.

---

```
while (a != b) {
    for (b = 0; b < 9; b++) { // b < 9
        if (b == a) {
            System.out.println("found the number " + b);
            return; // second change
        }
    }
}
```

---

**A few more comments:**

- There's no point to pass `a` and `b` as arguments to `search()` since the first thing you do is re-assign them.
- `b` is used only in the for-loop, no need to declare it at a wider scope
- The `while` loop is unnecessary

The following code will do the same:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    search();
}

private static void search() {    
    Random r = new Random();
    int a = r.nextInt(9);

    for (int b = 0; b < 9; b++) {
        if (b == a) {
            System.out.println("found the number " + b);
            return;
        }
    }    
}
```

It's worth mentioning that now that we don't have the wrapping `while` loop, even if we'll remove the return statement the code will still work!

Answer (score 0):

First, you may do wrong with `for` loop,

```
for(b=0;b == 9; b++）
```

the `b==9` is the **condition of the loop** has to meet. Obviously, this condition can never meet because `b = 0` at the first step.

so,

```
for (b = 0; b < 9; b++)
```

is okey.

And once the `a==b` is found, you have to break the `while` loop.

```
 while (a != b) {
        for (b = 0; b < 9; b++) {
            if (b == a) {
                System.out.println("found the number " + b);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Actually, the `while` loop is useless,the flowing is enough,

```
for(b = 0; b < 9; b++)
        {
             if (b == a) {
                 System.out.println("found the number " + b);
                 break;
             }
        }
```